# Is there a way to change how context.scale scales?

Tags: javascript, canvas

`Context2D.scale()` scales the canvas. But is there a way to set the scaling method for it? In my google research so far I've stumbed upon `image-rendering` but that isn't useful here
because that just defines how things are scaled when you scale things through CSS.

Comment: What's the use case exactly? There is still no way to disable antialiasing of most drawing methods. If you just want to scale up or down your content, then CSS might be a good idea for presentation, or you can draw your content at scale 1 and resize it through `drawImage` over your final canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see the

- [imageSmoothingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) and
- [imageSmoothingQuality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingQuality)

Comment: These work only for new contents drawn through `drawImage`.

Comment: I guess it should suffice for my use case though.